# How would you find the Q value in the Nernst equation if you were to change the temperature?

Tags: electrochemistry, stoichiometry

I'm studying how changing the temperature of the anode would affect the voltage produced within a galvanic cell. I think that the Nernst equation plays a role here but I am unsure how the reaction within the anode would be affected due to temperature. Would the reaction quotient change as temperature changes? Is it possible for the value of Q to be calculated during the reaction by using the voltage?

Comment: You have to consider also changing of the standard redox potential for different temperature that is linked to temperature change of the Gibbs energy of the redox reaction.

Comment: I'm unsure how to find the change to standard redox potential as it isn't feasible to find the change in entropy and change in enthalpy during the reaction. Can you elaborate further? @Poutnik

Comment: I have not said you can find it, but for simple cases. For many cases, it is matter of experimental work.